# Is "falls on" the right term in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Is "falls on" the right term in this sentence? Should it be "falls to"? I think it sounds incorrect to me — success doesn’t "fall on" some action, right? — but I can't put my finger on what should be done to salvage the sentence.

(I know I can change it to "... *depends* on executives finding a path ..." but I wanted to try to work with the original first.)

> The success of these strategies often falls on executives to find a path to profitability.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your sentence is that it is saying *the success* is what falls on the executives, but what it should say somehow is that *finding the path* falls on them.

It could be reorganized like:

> The success of these strategies **depends on finding** a path to profitability, **which often falls on executives**.

An entirely different option would be chaning *falls* to *fails*. In that case, *success* could be removed entirely:

> These strategies often **fail if executives cannot** find a path to profitability.

Comment: Yes; dummy it is often used with 'falls on': It often falls on executives to find a path to profitability to ensure the success of these strategies. 'Thus, it falls on those who manage the 15 000 elephants in captivity to be both at once very pragmatic and very sensitive.' [[FAO](http://www.fao.org/3/AD031E/ad031e06.htm)] [falls on= behooves]